# Derivatives: Combining Product & Chain Rules

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm working through the material on Khan Academy, and the question is:

**"Consider the function $f(x) = x^n\ln x$, defined for $x > 0$.

Determine, in terms of $n$, the value of $x$ for which $f'(x) = 0$"**

I was able to find the derivative $f'(x)= x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1)$ without any issues, but even with the hints walking through I wasn't able to work out how the rest works.

I think what I need to do now (although I could be wrong) is set the derivative = $0$, and then simplify so that $x = $ something in terms of $n$, so step 1 would be to set $x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1) = 0$.

I get lost here because I revealed the hints and they do this and then just get rid of the $x^{n-1}$ from the above without any explanation, so that: $n\ln x+1 = 0$.

From there it's just simple rearranging the equation, but I'm not sure how I get from my derivative $f'(x) = x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1)$ to the equation $n\ln x+1 = 0$.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just that the function is made out of two factors: $x^{n-1}$ and $n\ln x + 1$. You can bring the function down to $0$ if you can make at least one factor $0$. That is, you can look at when $x^{n-1}$ becomes $0$ (what the right part evaluates to doesn't matter anymore), or when the right factor $n\ln x+1$ becomes $0$, in which case you solve the equation $n\ln x +1=0$ as you said above.

Comment: Ah, so I just need to make one of the factors $= 0$. Thanks, ah it's not as complex as I thought. Cheers!

Comment: Also note the other answers, the other factor can indeed *never* be zero due to $x^{n-1} > 0$ for $x>0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$, so you don't even need to look at the other factor.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\ln x$ is not defined at $x=0$, thus when solving the equation $f'(x) = x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1)=0$  we know one of the factors must be zero, and since $x \ne 0$, we know it must be the second term.  Thus we divide both sides by $x^{n-1}$ to get $n \ln x + 1=0$

Answer (score 0):

You want $x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1) = 0$ but $x>0$, so $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},x^n\neq0$, so $x^{n-1}(n\ln x+1) = 0 \iff n\ln x+1=0 $